# what is the use-case of Python3 only `if` and `break` in `for`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python but

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py#L435-L437
https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/31669013d420c2a532f5be6c5631827fe36e6f70/src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py#L435-L437

I am watching the code of PIL of python then I can not understand here.

```
            for s in [8, 4, 2, 1]:
                if scale >= s:
                    break
```

Is the PIL library wrong?

I did:

watch the code and think about it.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are asking here. Are you confused about what this code snippet itself is doing, independently from its environment?

Comment: You know you could just run the code and e.g. see what values `s` will have depending on `scale`!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `s` will remain in scope after the loop, and contain the first value of that list which is smaller than or equal to `scale`.

In other words, this code "rounds down" `scale` to one of these four specific numbers.

I might have done `s = next(s for s in [8, 4, 2, 1] if scale >= s)` to make that more apparent, but this loop is probably slightly more performant.

Comment: Is `s` define by `for` statement?

Comment: Yes. ..........

Comment: Why `s` can used outside of `for`?

Comment: Because its scope *isn't* confined to `for`. Because `for` doesn't have its own scope.

Comment: Your alternative is not quite equivalent - the original loop will leave `s` with the value 1 even if none of the conditions are satisfied, but the alternative with `next(...)` will raise `StopIteration` in that case.